# RoR creating a form and passing back a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, hash

thanks in advance for looking at my issue. I'm new to programming and struggling with the concept of saving data to "foreign tables".

So this is a basic survey.  I have a list of questions, that have answers belonging to it.

Here is my code that iterates through all the questions and answers:

```
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
<ul><%= question.questiondescription %></ul>
<% @answers = question.answers %>
<% @answers.each do |answer| %>
<li><%= answer.answerdescription %></li>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

This works great.  However I want all the answers to be radio buttons and store the selections in another table.  I have another controller and table called "assessment_results".  It looks like this:

User_Id, Assessment_Id, Question_ID, Answer_Id

I need to create a new record in this table for each question and answer.  How would I go about doing this with having all the questions listed on one page?

So my thinking is I need a hash to push into that table for every question.
{[user_id:1, assessment_id:, question_id:1, answer_id:3]}

Comment: what do you mean by : ` to be radio buttons and store the selections in another table` ? Do you want to store the answer status ?

Comment: I want all the answers to be radio buttons, like in a form.  I thought that would be the best way to have users take the survey.  I then want the user to be able to submit their answers and store those answers in a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the radio_button_tag and parse the results yourself.

Here is the breakdown
Looking at your assessment_results table I assume you have an Assessment controller based on the 'assessment_id' column.

Lets use that to present the questions.

Here is the assessments/new.html.erb

```
<h1>New assessment</h1>
<%= form_for(@assessment) do |f| %>
  <% if @assessment.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@assessment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this assessment from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @assessment.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

      <% @questions.each do |question| %>
        <%= question.questiondescription %>
        <ul>
          <% @answers = question.answers %>
          <% @answers.each do |answer| %>
            <li><%= answer.answerdescription %><%= radio_button_tag("questions[#{question.id}]", answer.id) %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

So we have a standard assessment form that really just gives us the form structure and assessment button, we aren't going to actually use anything from it.

Best to build the view and then look at the source code in a browser.

The work is being done by the radio_button_tag, the first value "questions[#{question.id}]"

Will produce radio buttons with a name of "questions[1]" for the first group of questions and the value will be the answer id.

When rails sees a parameter like questions[1], it will put this into a hash called questions.

Here is the raw hash from the log when submitting the form with answers filled out:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"lwqT5y+xUaYvt/GBObpN+BBO3F4YO8XaEGWcpS84lVw=", "questions"=>{"1"=>"2", "2"=>"8", "3"=>"13", "4"=>"18", "5"=>"23"}, "commit"=>"Create Assessment"}
```

The questions hash is:

```
"questions"=>{"1"=>"2", "2"=>"8", "3"=>"13", "4"=>"18", "5"=>"23"}
```

Now in the assessments controller, for the create method, I did the following:

```
def create
  @assessment = Assessment.new(user_id: current_user.id)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @assessment.save
      params[:questions].each do |question, answer|
        AssessmentResult.create(user_id: current_user.id, assessment_id: @assessment.id,
          question_id: question, answer_id: answer)  
      end
      format.html { redirect_to @assessment, notice: 'Assessment was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @assessment }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @assessment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

First we are creating an assessment that belongs to the user, I am assuming that you are using Devise or a similar system that uses the current_user for the current logged in user.

Next after saving with @assessment.save, this gives us our @assessment.id that the assessment results will belong to.

So the core work is happening here:

```
params[:questions].each do |question, answer|
  AssessmentResult.create(user_id: current_user.id, assessment_id: @assessment.id
     question_id: question, answer_id: answer)  
  end
end
```

params[:questions] - this is the params question hash that was submitted by the form.

params[:questions].each do |question, answer| - this takes the hash and for each, entry splits it into the key and value with |key, value|, in this case the key was the question id and the value was the chosen answer id.

Now we store the answer in the AssessmentResult model/table with the create command.

Say you now want to display the results of the assessment with: /assessments/1/show

```
def show
  @assessment_results = AssessmentResult.where(assessment_id: @assessment.id)
end
```

Now you have the question and selected answer in the AssessmentResult

Make sure you set up your relations in the model:
app/models/assessment_result.rb

```
class AssessmentResult < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :answer
end
```

Simple display of quesiton and selected answer, you will have to add the 'correct answer' code yourself.

app/views/assessments/show.html.erb

```
<% @assessment_results.each do |ar| %>
  <%= ar.question.questiondescription %>: <%= ar.answer.answerdescription %>
  <br />
<% end %>
```

Comment: hey adam, thanks for the pointer.  Can you walk me through whats happening in this so I understand? I will wrap the iterators in form_for(@assessment_results)? Then I have a submit button and I'm submitting what exactly?  I'm only used to the normal forms that come with the scaffolding.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi Derek, I added in a lot more details, used the standard scaffold in a Rails 4.1 app. Hopefully this is a lot clearer and answers the question for you.

Comment: hey guys, thank you so much for your help! this really helped me.  Cant say enough for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, when you have a nested models, here's what you can do

```
<%=  form_for(@question) do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :answer do |ff| %>
        <%= ff.label :image, 'Tag:' %>
        <%= ff.checkbox :description, multiple: true, name: "answer[description]" %>
```

In your case, you have several `answers` belonging to some `question`, the principle is the same except you have to build specific ids for each `answer`, so I strongly suggest you these very helpful `railscast`

```
http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2
http://railscasts.com/episodes/75-complex-forms-part-3
```